# IIS to Apache connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, windows, database-connection

I am moving what looks like a pretty simple php/MSQL app from a Windows IIS server to a Cpanel/ Apache server.   The app works fine on existing IIS/MySQL server using this format to connect:

```
    <?php

    class Connection {
        var $conn;
        var $user = 'XX0000XX_XXadmXX';
        var $pass = 'XXXpasswordXXXX';
        var $dbname = 'XXckbXXX_XXX13XX';
        var $host = '74.0.0.0'; 
     function Connection() {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname,$this->conn) or die( "db-connect".      mysql_error());
     }

    function closedb() {
      //mysql_close(($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass ) or die( "db-close". mysql_error() );
     mysql_close($this->conn)or die( "db-close". mysql_error() );
    }
}
?>
```

I imported the DB into CPANEL/MySQL using PhpMyAdmin. 1st test failed due to $host not accepting IP address value.  After changing IP to localhost   - tested the connection with a DB connection script and that passed.  The error is that at I can connect with the same username and PW as Windows server.  But after logging in any link I click in the admin kicks me out.

Any clues would be helpful - let me know if I can provide any information that would help.  I am thinking that there may be a windows specific change that needs to happen or something to do with the the DB host.

Here are some values in a settings file - before the Ip addresses were set with domain name - set with IP to test:

```
    define('ADMIN_MANAGEMENT', "sitename");
define('FROM_NAME', "Admin");
define('SITE', "sitename");
define('SITE_NAME', "http://74.0.0.0/");
define('ADMIN_ID', "dwayne@fair.com");
define('KEYWORD', "sitename");
define('SITE_URL',"http://74.0.0.0/");
define('SITEIMGPATH', "http://74.0.0.0/public/images/");
define('ITEMS_PER_PAGE', "15");
define('PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE', "5");
define('UPLOAD_FILES', "uploads/files/");
define('UPLOAD_IMAGES', "uploads/images/");
define('SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH',190);
define('SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT',77);
define('PROFILENAME', "Welcome to domain.com");
define('CARID',1000);
define('RESIZE_IMAGE_WIDTH',400);
define('RESIZE_IMAGE_HEIGHT',300);

/*Live path*/
define("ROOT", "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/admin/");
define("ROOTS", "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/admin/");
```

Comment: Not sure if you have your real credentials in there, but be careful when posting an in development.

Comment: Well this _sounds_ like those credentials simply have no right to connect. Did you setup the permissions for that user correctly inside the MySQL server _and did you load them afterwards_? Note that different permission rules may be defined for different connection scenarios in MySQL.